# SQL Abstraction, Functionality to represent SQL-Interface in API

Tags: php, sql

Well, first sorry for the title if it's not clear enough. I didn't know how to explain it more clearly.

So, the idea is to have a class (I'm using PHP, however, it's more general idea), to represent the SQL functionality but via the class methods. For example, imagine the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT p_id, p_name FROM tbl_products
```

It could be something like this:

```
$API->Data->Action = 'select';
$API->Data->Fields = 'p_id, p_name';    // comma separated
$API->Data->Table = 'tbl_products';
```

And I can reassemble it like:

```
$Query = $API->Data->Action . ' ' . $API->Data->Fields . ' FROM ' . 
         $API->Data->Table . ' WHERE available = 1';
```

The `API` should provide for some programmers, however it could be short, simple and easy to use. If they want to run their very-own SQL statements, they have that ability also.

**Question:**

Which keywords you will use as the function names' which could be clear for both novice and professional programmers, but not very similar to SQL standard keywords?

For example, instead of `LIMIT 0, 15` I can use something like `First` and `Last` and then combine it with the offset. But what about something like `ASC` and `DESC`? `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE` are enough clear, but for a person that let say he doesn't know anything about SQL, `SELECT` could be a little bit confusing.

- Please let me know your general ideas
- And offer me your desired 'keywords' also

I know that it might not look like a serious question somehow, but I really appreciate your help and ideas! For me they are much more than just a 'keyword', and that's why I'm asking for your ideas! Thank you everyone for any answer!

**Solution:**

I finally came up with this:

```
// Pure SQL Query
$API->Database->Query('SQL HERE');
$API->Database->Result;    // It contains the results as an Object

// For 'SELECT' you don't need any command, just Process() it ...
$API->Data->Table = 'Products';
$API->Data->Fields = 'p_id, p_name';
$API->Data->Offset = 'last';
$API->Data->Limit = 15;
$API->Data->Process();

// 'UPDATE', need passing some variables like above plus something like 'WHERE'
$API->Data->Save();

// 'INSERT'
$API->Data->Add();

// Save() without 'WHERE' would insert also

// 'DELETE'
$API->Data->Delete();
```

I'm still looking to improve it as there are still some unclear points there, so feel free to share your ideas! :)

Comment: '...but not very similar to SQL standard keywords...' - why on Earth do you have this specific requirement? How do you think to make your version of <del>wheel</del> SQL::Abstract interesting to professionals, if they basically will have to relearn another language to use it efficiently?

Comment: check out http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html, it abstracts away the sql while providing the tools to use sql if required. Also almost every ORM has it's own api or version of SQL abstraction

Comment: you know SQL by itself is something that you have to go and learn it. I have to use something that novice programmers do NOT need to learn anything to deal with that. That's why I want them to be simple and clear ...

Comment: @RockyFord Thanks man, but that's somehow the SQL by itself, just a little bit more confusing for a beginner. (I've already worked on Zend)

Comment: It's just PHP. If that confused you, try an ORM/Dbal like Doctrine.

Comment: @RockyFord it's not confusing for me as I've already worked on Zend, but I'm sure a novice guy prefers to write the plain SQL instead of going to that way. I want to avoid that additional complexity on my API ...

Answer (score 1):

You could build something like this:

```
class DBAdapter extends PDO
{
  public function __construct( array $params)
  {
     // construct the connection
  }

  public function Select ($table)
  {
    // do stuff for a table select
    return $this;
  }

  public function Count ($table)
  {
    // do stuff for a table count
    return $this;
  }


  public function Where ($condition)
  {
    // do stuff for a where
    return $this;
  }

  public function Execute ()
  {
    // execute stuff
    return $result;
  }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
$db = new DBAdapter(array('host' => 'localhost'));
$results = $db->Select('mytable')->Where('id > 2')->Execute();
```

Comment: I'm exactly looking to replace 'SELECT' and 'WHERE' clauses with new and more clear names. Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: You can name the functions as you like. You could look how C# LINQ is implemented.

Comment: Yes, I know that I can/have to choose names by myself. But I'm looking for that names here ... LINQ is good, but still so similar to SQL syntax ...